# Redirect after posting to another page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am working on a react coding template where after clicking on submit, it shows me a successful message and stays on the same page. I would like to add a redirect to the submit button if successful without changing the design. My ./AskPage component uses interfaces from ./Form. How do I add a redirect to the ./AskPage once I click on submit? Below is my code

./Form code is:

```
import { FC, useState, createContext, FormEvent } from 'react';
import { PrimaryButton, gray5, gray6 } from './Styles';
/** @jsx jsx */
import { css, jsx } from '@emotion/core';

export interface Values {
  [key: string]: any;
}

export interface Errors {
  [key: string]: string[];
}

export interface Touched {
  [key: string]: boolean;
}
/* export interface onSubmit {
  [key: string]: any
} */

interface FormContextProps {
  values: Values;
  setValue?: (fieldName: string, value: any) => void;
  errors: Errors;
  validate?: (fieldName: string) => void;
  touched: Touched;
  setTouched?: (fieldName: string) => void;
}
export const FormContext = createContext<FormContextProps>({
  values: {},
  errors: {},
  touched: {},
});

type Validator = (value: any, args?: any) => string;

export const required: Validator = (value: any): string =>
  value === undefined || value === null || value === ''
    ? 'This must be populated'
    : '';

export const minLength: Validator = (value: any, length: number): string =>
  value && value.length < length
    ? `This must be at least ${length} characters`
    : '';

interface Validation {
  validator: Validator;
  arg?: any;
}

interface ValidationProp {
  [key: string]: Validation | Validation[];
}

export interface SubmitResult {
  success: boolean;
  errors?: Errors;
}

interface Props {
  submitCaption?: string;
  validationRules?: ValidationProp;
  onSubmit: (values: Values) => Promise<SubmitResult>;
  successMessage?: string;
  failureMessage?: string;
}
export const Form: FC<Props> = ({
  submitCaption,
  children,
  validationRules,
  onSubmit,
  successMessage = 'Success!',
  failureMessage = 'Something went wrong',
}) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState<Values>({});
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState<Errors>({});
  const [touched, setTouched] = useState<Touched>({});
  const [submitting, setSubmitting] = useState(false);
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const [submitError, setSubmitError] = useState(false);

  const validate = (fieldName: string): string[] => {
    if (!validationRules) {
      return [];
    }
    if (!validationRules[fieldName]) {
      return [];
    }
    const rules = Array.isArray(validationRules[fieldName])
      ? (validationRules[fieldName] as Validation[])
      : ([validationRules[fieldName]] as Validation[]);
    const fieldErrors: string[] = [];
    rules.forEach(rule => {
      const error = rule.validator(values[fieldName], rule.arg);
      if (error) {
        fieldErrors.push(error);
      }
    });
    const newErrors = { ...errors, [fieldName]: fieldErrors };
    setErrors(newErrors);
    return fieldErrors;
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (validateForm()) {
      setSubmitting(true);
      setSubmitError(false);
      const result = await onSubmit(values);
      setErrors(result.errors || {});
      setSubmitError(!result.success);
      setSubmitting(false);
      setSubmitted(true);
    }
  };

  const validateForm = () => {
    const newErrors: Errors = {};
    let haveError: boolean = false;
    if (validationRules) {
      Object.keys(validationRules).forEach(fieldName => {
        newErrors[fieldName] = validate(fieldName);
        if (newErrors[fieldName].length > 0) {
          haveError = true;
        }
      });
    }
    setErrors(newErrors);
    return !haveError;
  };

  return (
    <FormContext.Provider
      value={{
        values,
        setValue: (fieldName: string, value: any) => {
          setValues({ ...values, [fieldName]: value });
        },
        errors,
        validate,
        touched,
        setTouched: (fieldName: string) => {
          setTouched({ ...touched, [fieldName]: true });
        },
      }}
    >
      <form noValidate={true} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <fieldset
          disabled={submitting || (submitted && !submitError)}
          id="fieldset"     >
          {children}
          <div id="children"          >
            <PrimaryButton type="submit">{submitCaption}</PrimaryButton>
          </div>
          {submitted && submitError && (
            <p id="failure"            >
              {failureMessage}
            </p>)}
          {submitted && !submitError && (
            <p id="success"            >
              {successMessage}
            </p>)}
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </FormContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

My ./AskpPage is:

```
import React, { useState, FC } from 'react';
import { Page } from './Page';
import { Form, required, minLength, Values } from './Form';
import { Field } from './Field';
import { postQuestion } from './QuestionsData';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { isPropertySignature } from 'typescript';

export const AskPage = () => {
  const handleSubmit = async (values: Values) => {
    const question = await postQuestion({
      title: values.title,
      content: values.content,
      userName: 'Fred',
      created: new Date(),
    });
    return { success: question ? true : false };
  };

  return (
    <Page title="Ask a Question">
 {/* I want to add a redirect to this form once I click Submit Your Question */}
      <Form
        submitCaption="Submit Your Question"
        validationRules={{
          title: [{ validator: required }, { validator: minLength, arg: 10 }],
          content: [{ validator: required }, { validator: minLength, arg: 20 }],
        }}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        failureMessage="There was a problem with your question"
        successMessage="Your question was successfully submitted"
      >
        <Field name="title" label="Title" />
        <Field name="content" label="Content" type="TextArea" />
      </Form>
    </Page>
  );
};
export default AskPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code example to redirect after my form submissions in react. I basically do all that is needed and save the answer then call the appropriate function to take me to an appropriate page. That page may then go get the answer. Another way would be to use props and import another page...

```
function viewPage() {
  let url = window.location.origin;
  console.log('viewPage', url)
  url=url.concat('/SelfAssessment')
  window.open(url, "_blank");
}
```

Comment: so after <./Form>, do I just do {viewPage}?

Comment: As you are coding in React you just call a function after you have dealt with the data from the form. It seems to me you handle the data in handlesubmit, so at the end of validation there is a line: setSubmitted(true); enter  viewPage(); on the next line and maybe that is what you want. 

The function viewPage() needs to be in the /Form file, cut, paste, and edit accordingly. 

Rename and rewrite the function to go where you want to go as you wish.